# Prism single instance viewmodel, used by several views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, module, prism

I have a relatively complex modular application that seems like a great fit for the Prism library and the Shell/Module architecture.

I'm hung up on the possibility of the following:

My application will connect to many physical devices, for this example I want to connect to a Laser over RS232. I will need only a handful of methods for the laser to perform, such as Connect, GetHeight, SendCommand, and Disconnect. So all of this should be defined in a laser class.

Now, I need a LaserModule will have multiple Views that are spread throughout my application. One View might constantly poll the laser using GetHeight and show the value, another View might be a simple button that does a single GetHeight and shows the result in a dialog. Another View might just be another button that gets added to a listview region (among other module views) that when clicked goes to the settings View for the LaserModule.

With that said, there can be only 1 instance of the laser class per LaserModule because I can only be connected to the RS232 port once. Also, I'd imagine all the Views would shared the same (single instance) ViewModel since a lot of the functionality is shared across the different Views.

Does this make any sense? I will have many regions, but as I swap out Views back and forth in these regions I never want to create more than the one instance of each View/View Model.

Finally, the application should be able to handle multiple LaserModules for each laser physically connected (but each would have their own separate set of single instance Views/ViewModels).

Any insight is greatly appreciated, this picture sums up roughly what I'm trying to do: [Laser Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOTlA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a Laser service and that would be registered with the container as a singleton.  Then your ViewModel would use the service.  Do not try to have singleton ViewModels.  That's asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks Brian, where might it make sense to do that registration of the laser class, right inside the initialization of my LaserModule? If I need 2/3/4+ lasers in my application, would it be best practice to simply do the registration of laser classes in a foreach loop during initialization? Or does it make sense to add a 2nd/3rd/4th/+ LaserModule, and each of them has their own singleton laser? Or is that decision completely trivial because both are possible?

Comment: Hi Brian. I thought to register singleton child viewModels so I can pass them as parameters to their parent viewModels. That way parent viewmodel can invoke child viewmodel's commands.
Can you explain in more details what are the downsides of this approach? And how else can I reuse viewmodel commands in different views?